# How to Convert GraphQLSchema Object to Type Definitions

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Let's say i have a GraphQL Schema like:

```
type author {
    id: Int
    name: String
    rating: Int  
}
```

You can use this type definition to generate an executable schema that can be queried on.

But in case i don't have the above type definitions, but only have GraphQLSchema object obtained through the introspection query, how do i generate the above type definitions?

I checked out graphql/utilities which had a `printSchema` method, that accepts a GraphQLSchema object and prints a string. But i can't seem to filter the output for a particular node alone, since i don't want the entire schema. Parsing the string output is not desirable.

Pointing to right methods is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [`printSchema`](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#printschema) it is not mentioned in the docs, but [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) exports `printType` method exactly for this! See in [the sources](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/index.js#L346). For example with [graphql-iso-date](https://github.com/excitement-engineer/graphql-iso-date).

```
const { printType } = require('graphql');
const { GraphQLDate } = require('graphql-iso-date');

console.log(printType(GraphQLDate));
```

It prints:

```
"""
A date string, such as 2007-12-03, compliant with the `full-date` format
outlined in section 5.6 of the RFC 3339 profile of the ISO 8601 standard for
representation of dates and times using the Gregorian calendar.
"""
scalar Date
```

Which can be simply put to [`makeExecutableSchema`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#makeExecutableSchema) functions `typeDefs` parameter.