# How to pass existing GraphQLSchema object to Apollo makeExecutableSchema function

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

How can I pass an existing GraphQLSchema object like [graphql-iso-date](https://github.com/excitement-engineer/graphql-iso-date) to the `makeExecutableSchema` function, to use it along with my string-defined types and resolver functions? Say in following type definition I want the `date` property to be `GraphQLDate` from the mentioned package.

```
import { GraphQLDate, GraphQLTime, GraphQLDateTime } from 'graphql-iso-date';

let typeDefs = [];
typeDefs.push(`
  type MyType {
    date: Date
  }
`);

let resolvers = {
  Query: () => { /* ... */ },
};

makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `resolvers` map, which is passed to the `makeExecutableSchema` does accept the `GraphQLScalarType` and the Date type is scalar. We still have to add the types into the `typeDefs` manually though...

```
typeDefs.push('scalar Date');
```

and

```
resolvers.Date = GraphQLDate;
```

So I've created a *module of external scalars* in my project and am doing

```
import externalTypes from './externalTypes';
import printType from 'graphql';

// Define my typeDefs and resolvers here

for (let externalType of externalTypes) {
  let { name } = externalType;
  typeDefs.push(printType(externalType));
  resolvers[name] = externalType;
}

makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

I figured it by trial/failure and only then found it in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars.html#custom-scalars), thus posting. Also I still don't know how would I add a non-scalar type this way (well other than manually writing it's type definition).

Also the `printType` function, which prints schema definition from type object passed, becomes handy here (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50407691/336753) for more detail).